# Getting 'SyntaxError: invalid property id' in jquery template

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting 'SyntaxError: invalid property id' in the {{if}} condition inside template defined below. I'm new with Jquery templates. Can somebody please correct my mistake?

```
$.template('familyMembers', '<tr> \
                        <td>Nature Of User:</td> \
                        <td><input type="radio" name="${Type}" value="adult" {{if ${Type_Value} == "adult"}} checked {{/if}} />Adult \
                            <input type="radio" name="${Type}" value="child" {{if ${Type_Value} == "child"}} checked {{/if}} />Child \
                        </td> \
                            </tr>');
```

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: is it supposed to be $Type_Value not {$Type_Value}? Also what is the error?

Comment: I'm using jquery.tmpl.js

Comment: I think it is supposed to be like this ${Type_Value}, and the error is 'invalid property id'.

Comment: Are you aware that the plugin is deprecated and no longer supported or under active development?  If so, can you post your markup as well?  Looking at the docs, it looks like you are using it wrong.

Comment: No, i did not know that. It was working fine before i added the if statement in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by @drneel i tried to look in the specific documentation of the plugin I'm using, and found out that the correct syntax was,

```
$.template('familyMembers', '<tr> \
                    <td>Nature Of User:</td> \
                    <td><input type="radio" name="${Type}" value="adult" {{if Type_Value == "adult"}} checked {{/if}} />Adult \
                        <input type="radio" name="${Type}" value="child" {{if Type_Value == "child"}} checked {{/if}} />Child \
                    </td> \
                        </tr>');
```

And it resolved the issue.